# Use Jest for a method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm using for the first time jest.
So I want to test this method:

```
public static getProjectBranch(toto: any): string {
    if ("branch" in toto) {
        return toto.branch;
    } else {
        return "master";
    }
}
```

This method is inside a class totoService.ts

What I'm doing in totoService.spec.ts :

```
describe("Test get Project Branch", () => {
test("branch is in component", () => expect(getProjectBranch()).toBe(""));
});
```

I want to know if what i'm doing is good or no
And how can I import the method getProjectBranch in the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your method `getProjectBranch` is static you could simply do like shown below:

```
describe("TotoService",() => {
  describe('getProjectBranch', () => {
    test("branch is in component",() => {
      const toto = {branch:''}; //create your test object here
      expect(totoService.getProjectBranch(toto)).toEqual(''); //call static method of TotoService
    })
  })
})
```

If you would like to call non static methods you need to create an instance of the totoService `beforeEach` test:

```
describe("TotoService",() => {

  let totoService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    totoService = new TotoService();
  })

  describe('getProjectBranch', () => {
    test("branch is in component",() => {
      const toto = {branch:''};
      expect(totoService.getProjectBranch(toto)).toEqual('');
    })
  })
})
```